# Wireless will not connect with an AzureWave chipset

Tags: 10.10, wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 on the same machine as my windows setup.

However, it will not connect to my wireless network. It can see its there, it can attempt to connect, yet it will never connect. It will keep bringing up the password prompt everyso often.

I have tried turning my security to WEP, I ended up turning it back to WPA2. It is set to AES (noted a few threads on google about that).

Can you assist? I would love to dive into Ubuntu, but without the internet its pointless.

```
lshw -C network
```

```
    *-network               
           description: Ethernet interface
           product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
           vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
           logical name: eth0
           version: 02
           serial: 00:1d:92:ea:cc:62
           capacity: 1GB/s
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.020.00-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
           resources: irq:29 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:feaff000-feafffff memory:f8ff0000-f8ffffff(prefetchable) memory:feac0000-feadffff(prefetchable)
      *-network
           description: Wireless interface
           physical id: 1
           logical name: wlan0
           serial: 00:15:af:72:a4:38
           capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

```
iwconfig
```

```
    lo        no wireless extensions.

    eth0      no wireless extensions.

    wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Wuggawoo"  
              Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
              Tx-Power=9 dBm   
              Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
              Encryption key:off
              Power Management:on
```

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

```
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback
```

```
deamon.log
```

```
    Jan 19 04:17:09 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1289]: Authentication with 94:44:52:0d:22:0d timed out.
    Jan 19 04:17:09 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  associating -> disconnected
    Jan 19 04:17:09 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  disconnected -> scanning
    Jan 19 04:17:11 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1289]: WPS-AP-AVAILABLE 
    Jan 19 04:17:11 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1289]: Trying to associate with 94:44:52:0d:22:0d (SSID='Wuggawoo' freq=2437 MHz)
    Jan 19 04:17:11 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  scanning -> associating
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long.
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): device state change: 5 -> 6 (reason 0)
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   Activation (wlan0/wireless): asking for new secrets
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): device state change: 6 -> 4 (reason 0)
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): device state change: 4 -> 5 (reason 0)
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'Wuggawoo' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   Config: added 'ssid' value 'Wuggawoo'
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   Config: added 'psk' value ''
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager: nm_setting_802_1x_get_pkcs11_engine_path: assertion `NM_IS_SETTING_802_1X (setting)' failed
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager: nm_setting_802_1x_get_pkcs11_module_path: assertion `NM_IS_SETTING_802_1X (setting)' failed
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  associating -> disconnected
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
    Jan 19 04:17:12 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  disconnected -> scanning
    Jan 19 04:17:13 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1289]: WPS-AP-AVAILABLE 
    Jan 19 04:17:13 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1289]: Trying to associate with 94:44:52:0d:22:0d (SSID='Wuggawoo' freq=2437 MHz)
    Jan 19 04:17:13 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  scanning -> associating
    Jan 19 04:17:23 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1289]: Authentication with 94:44:52:0d:22:0d timed out.
    Jan 19 04:17:23 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  associating -> disconnected
    Jan 19 04:17:23 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  disconnected -> scanning
    Jan 19 04:17:24 ubuntu AptDaemon: INFO: Initializing daemon
    Jan 19 04:17:25 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1289]: WPS-AP-AVAILABLE 
    Jan 19 04:17:25 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1289]: Trying to associate with 94:44:52:0d:22:0d (SSID='Wuggawoo' freq=2437 MHz)
    Jan 19 04:17:25 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  scanning -> associating
    Jan 19 04:17:27 ubuntu NetworkManager:   wlan0: link timed out.
```

```
kern.log
```

```
    Jan 19 04:18:11 ubuntu kernel: [  142.420024] wlan0: direct probe to AP 94:44:52:0d:22:0d timed out
    Jan 19 04:18:13 ubuntu kernel: [  144.333847] wlan0: direct probe to AP 94:44:52:0d:22:0d (try 1)
    Jan 19 04:18:13 ubuntu kernel: [  144.539996] wlan0: direct probe to AP 94:44:52:0d:22:0d (try 2)
    Jan 19 04:18:13 ubuntu kernel: [  144.750027] wlan0: direct probe to AP 94:44:52:0d:22:0d (try 3)
    Jan 19 04:18:14 ubuntu kernel: [  144.940022] wlan0: direct probe to AP 94:44:52:0d:22:0d timed out
    Jan 19 04:18:25 ubuntu kernel: [  155.832995] wlan0: direct probe to AP 94:44:52:0d:22:0d (try 1)
    Jan 19 04:18:25 ubuntu kernel: [  156.030046] wlan0: direct probe to AP 94:44:52:0d:22:0d (try 2)
    Jan 19 04:18:25 ubuntu kernel: [  156.230039] wlan0: direct probe to AP 94:44:52:0d:22:0d (try 3)
    Jan 19 04:18:25 ubuntu kernel: [  156.430039] wlan0: direct probe to AP 94:44:52:0d:22:0d timed out
```

```
syslog
```

```
    Jan 19 04:18:46 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1289]: Authentication with 94:44:52:0d:22:0d timed out.
    Jan 19 04:18:46 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  associating -> disconnected
    Jan 19 04:18:46 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  disconnected -> scanning
    Jan 19 04:18:48 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1289]: WPS-AP-AVAILABLE 
    Jan 19 04:18:48 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1289]: Trying to associate with 94:44:52:0d:22:0d (SSID='Wuggawoo' freq=2437 MHz)
    Jan 19 04:18:48 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  scanning -> associating
    Jan 19 04:18:48 ubuntu kernel: [  178.833905] wlan0: direct probe to AP 94:44:52:0d:22:0d (try 1)
    Jan 19 04:18:48 ubuntu kernel: [  179.030035] wlan0: direct probe to AP 94:44:52:0d:22:0d (try 2)
    Jan 19 04:18:48 ubuntu kernel: [  179.230020] wlan0: direct probe to AP 94:44:52:0d:22:0d (try 3)
    Jan 19 04:18:48 ubuntu kernel: [  179.433634] wlan0: direct probe to AP 94:44:52:0d:22:0d timed out
```

```
lspci
```

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge
    00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (ext gfx port 0)
    00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
    00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
    00:11.0 SATA controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    00:12.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB OHCI0 Controller
    00:12.1 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700 USB OHCI1 Controller
    00:12.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB EHCI Controller
    00:13.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB OHCI0 Controller
    00:13.1 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700 USB OHCI1 Controller
    00:13.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB EHCI Controller
    00:14.0 SMBus: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3a)
    00:14.1 IDE interface: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 IDE Controller
    00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
    00:14.3 ISA bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 LPC host controller
    00:14.4 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
    00:14.5 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB OHCI2 Controller
    00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K10 [Opteron, Athlon64, Sempron] HyperTransport Configuration
    00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K10 [Opteron, Athlon64, Sempron] Address Map
    00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K10 [Opteron, Athlon64, Sempron] DRAM Controller
    00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K10 [Opteron, Athlon64, Sempron] Miscellaneous Control
    00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K10 [Opteron, Athlon64, Sempron] Link Control
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G80 [GeForce 8800 GTS] (rev a2)
    02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02)
    03:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller
```

```
lsusb
```

```
    Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 003: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
    Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045e:0730 Microsoft Corp. 
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 13d3:3247 IMC Networks 802.11 n/g/b Wireless LAN Adapter
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0718:0628 Imation Corp. 
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:08c2 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam PTZ
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2228 Standard Microsystems Corp. 9-in-2 Card Reader
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

With no security on my router I still can't connect, I get:

```
    Jan 19 15:58:01 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1165]: Authentication with 94:44:52:0d:22:0d timed out.
    Jan 19 15:58:01 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  associating -> disconnected
    Jan 19 15:58:01 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  disconnected -> scanning
    Jan 19 15:58:02 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1165]: WPS-AP-AVAILABLE 
    Jan 19 15:58:02 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1165]: Trying to associate with 94:44:52:0d:22:0d (SSID='Wuggawoo' freq=2437 MHz)
    Jan 19 15:58:02 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1165]: Association request to the driver failed
    Jan 19 15:58:02 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  scanning -> associating
    Jan 19 15:58:05 ubuntu NetworkManager:   wlan0: link timed out.
    Jan 19 15:58:07 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1165]: Authentication with 94:44:52:0d:22:0d timed out.
    Jan 19 15:58:07 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  associating -> disconnected
    Jan 19 15:58:07 ubuntu NetworkManager:   (wlan0): supplicant connec
```

Comment: Can you open System / Administration / System log and look for relevant lines in the end while you are trying to connect?

Comment: done. also put some commands and there results.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't tell us what the wireless network hardware is. If it's a built-in or PCI network card, please paste in the output of `lspci`. If it's a USB dongle, then paste in the output of `lsusb`. If it's a laptop, tell us its make and model too please.

Comment: Its r8168 (realtek)

Comment: [r8168 is a wired ethernet chipset](http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=12) from what I can see.

Comment: According to the MAC address it's a chip from AzureWave (USB dongle).

Comment: The only dongle in my computer is for a logitech wireless mouse.

Comment: @azz0r: Can you please append the output of `lspci` and `lsusb` so we can properly determine the hardware and answer the question.

Comment: Hello Azz0r. Can you please test the router without any password. No WEP o WPA and also make sure it is using the same type of Wifi, what i mean is Wifi A/B/G/N. I recommend G to make sure since it is the most popular. Check that in the router, no encryption and using G.

Comment: Done. I find it really strange that its listing Bus 002 Device 003: ID 13d3:3247 IMC Networks 802.11 n/g/b Wireless LAN Adapter under USB.

The only thing I can think of is the ethernet ports on the back come from a device inside the computer attached to the motherboard via USB

Comment: @CYREX Done, still wouldnt connect, really strange. I have put the errors it got then at the bottom of the original post.

Comment: A ok did not see the part about been USB. Did you remove the encryption so it is OPEN and does not ask for a password? then do something like  

iwconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 up
iwconfig wlan0 essid Wuggawoo
dhclient (Just in case)

It should not ask for a password or anything since you left the router opened. If it is like my Link Dir-655 which was hell until i upgraded it the firmware. It was giving me problems with a Broadcom and a Ralink i have.

Also verify in the router if when you are trying to connect the router shows the connection

Comment: is it the case that when you have set your router to accept any non-WPA connections you forgot to erase the settings from 'edit connections' in Network Manager ? Reason I ask is because your non-WPA connection shows wpa-supplicant having an error which i thought was the program that deals with WPA connections. For non WPA connections i think it shouldnt be using that, so perhaps you have switched it to an OPEN network but forgot to change your settings on your client to reflect that ? Assuming your ubuntu install is a fresh one and you havent fiddled too much, this looks to me like a router is

Comment: You should use WPA2-PSK WEP is all broken and not worth bothering with. From the traces posted you seem to be having an authentication issue, please double check the password, in the last trace it is still calling wpa_supplicant so some form of security is still enabled.

Answer (score 1):

While this May not completely Answer your Question, I have a Desktop box with a Similar realtek chip set, that also by MAC says Azure wave, The advice i can give is it works in 11.04 and 11.10, so my guess is its a Kernel/driver issue